How do I use `DateTimeOffset`s to show 23 or 25 hours on a day when clocks change?
New York switched from Eastern Standard Time to Eastern Daylight Time on March 10th, 2024.
I believe the time zone ID "Eastern Standard Time" maps to "America/New_York" in .NET.
However, when I cound the number of hours on March 10th, 2024 using this timezone, I see 24 hours and not 23 hours (since clocks moved forward 1 hour at 2am).
(This snippet uses F#, but a C# solution would obviously work too.)
open System

let est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")
let start = DateTimeOffset(DateTime(2024, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), est.BaseUtcOffset)
let stop = DateTimeOffset(DateTime(2024, 3, 11, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), est.BaseUtcOffset)
(stop - start).TotalHours
# 24.0


It is not clear exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

You're explicitly using the BaseUtcOffset, which doesn't change over time. Don't do that. I don't know that there's any direct way of getting the right DateTimeOffset from TimeZoneInfo, rather than calling GetUtcOffset() and constructing it yourself - but just using the BaseUtcOffset is really not going to work. Personally I'd use my Noda Time library (https://nodatime.org) which makes all of this much clearer and less error prone but obviously I'm biased...

Currently, you're always using an offset of est.BaseUtcOffset, which means both of your DateTimeOffset values have the same UTC offset... so yes, that will return 24 hours. I don't think TimeZoneInfo has a built-in way of going from a DateTime to a DateTimeOffset, but it's fairly easy to write one, and then call that:
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var start = ConvertToDateTimeOffset(tz, new DateTime(2024, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0));
var end = ConvertToDateTimeOffset(tz, new DateTime(2024, 3, 11, 0, 0, 0));
Console.WriteLine(end - start);

DateTimeOffset ConvertToDateTimeOffset(TimeZoneInfo tz, DateTime dt)
{
    // Note: it's unclear what happens if dt is ambiguous or skipped :(
    var offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(dt);
    return new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);
}

Output: 23:00:00
Personally I'd use Noda Time instead, as IMO it makes things clearer. Disclaimer: I'm biased as the author of Noda Time.
using NodaTime;

DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
ZonedDateTime start = tz.AtStrictly(new LocalDateTime(2024, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0));
ZonedDateTime end = tz.AtStrictly(new LocalDateTime(2024, 3, 11, 0, 0, 0));

Duration diff = end - start;
Console.WriteLine(diff);


Jon maybe biased, but I'm not. I can vouch for NodaTime. It's the best .NET date&time library out there and it's the first lib I add to any project.
